# What is the reason behind windows 7 going very slow and Kaspersky not detecting a single virus?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, anti-virus, kaspersky

I have ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 installed on my laptop. The windows 7 was working well for a few years and suddenly it started giving problem and became unbearably slow. i suspected virus and intalled Kaspersky antivirus. But no use as Kaspersky (after updating) could not detect a single virus. Hence I re-istalled Win 7 and the kaspersky again on the machine and just after a few hours it started giving problem and became terribly slow. Is the problem because of a virus or the Hard disk. On the other hand ubuntu was working fine till I re-installed Win7, but now I can't boot in ubuntu. I have valueble data on the disk. Also to mention, a few months back  two of my external hard disks crashed (a 160 GB hard disk is not able to be detected) and (1 TB not able to open in windows or any machine except in ubuntu where it opens but the data cannot be retrived). Both these external (USB) disks crashed while I was using windows 7 (but then at that time Win 7 was working properly).

Is there any common reason behind the failure of these external and internal hard disks. More importantly, How can I solve this problem and retrieve my data as well. Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a possibility of boot sector virus or some kind of viruses causing crash of hard disks?

Comment: Kaspersky isn't designed to located the type of infections that slow down your computer. You want to look for what is known as Malware. There are lots of good questions on this topic I suggest you follow the advice contained in the many good answers. **What is more likely is the HDD is about to fail.** Boot sector infections are really rare if you are running a modern operating released in the last 5 years.  As for your other hdd failures, if you don't have backups of those, then the data is already gone.

Comment: I almost agree with @Ramhound but the data is probably not gone... Yet.  If the data really is valuable, take it to a computer store and get it backed NOW, before you do anything else, as most likely the problem will get worse if it is a hard drive error, and the data could become unrecoverable.

Comment: @davidgo - His HDDs are not even spinning, special data recovery services can run you hundreds of dollars. Seagate actually has a very reasonable hdd data recovery service, it costs $99 USD for a quote, and you decide if you want to move forward on the quote. It might be limited to just Seagate HDDs though.

Comment: @Ramhound - Why do you think his HDD's are not spinning ? His post implies the opposite when he says things are going unbearably slow, which indicates to me the problem is most likely bad sectors.   If someone brought a disk like that to me, first thing I'd do is throw it in a Linux box and execute (Gnu) DDRescue on it until it went slow, then read in reverse, then leave it on until it dies.  [ In fairness, I'd probably read the SMART data off first just to see what the drive thinks of itself ]

Comment: @davidgo - I guess you are right.  I just take the fact Windows cannot even load the files on the hdd as the point where, the data is likely gone, as I said there are reasonable services that allow you to get a quote.  My experience with reallocation problems were not good.